# when jsf validation failed, ajax is skipped

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have this code :

```
<p:inputText id="abc"  value="#{myBean.name}" >

    <f:validator validatorId="mandatoryInput" />

    <p:ajax  event="change"  update="..."  listener="#{myBean.myFunction()}" />

</oct:inputTextUpper>
```

When the Validator throw a new ValidatorException,  is skipped. Is it possible to launch myFunction() even if validation is failed ?
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the business usecase? I'm curious to this since I never had the need for such a feature. Might be that you have an http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default JSF behavior. As a work around you could work with f:event:

```
<p:inputText id="abc" value="#{myBean.name}">
    <f:validator validatorId="mandatoryInput" />
    <p:ajax  event="change"  update="..."  listener="#{myBean.myFunction}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{myBean.callMyFunction}" />
</p:inputText>
```

In MyBean add the following method:

```
public void callMyFunction(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
    UIInput input = (UIInput) e.getComponent();
    if (!input.isValid()) {
        myFunction();
    }
}
```